# How can I display/control no. of COLUMNS by variable as I have table with 120 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have requirement from users that they always wants test results as `quarterly` to the date of individual's `FIRST ADMISSION`.

The question is, can I control no of test by `variable`? For example if user want `20 test`, I would be able to assign those tests to the `variables` and set the `LOOP` to `20` so that I do not have to write `CASE statements` for each and every test.

Any help or alternative solution would be sincerely appreciated.

```
SELECT  Q.ID,
    Q.First_Admission,      
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN -365  AND -1 THEN Test_1    ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS BEFORE_1_Yr,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 0   AND 90   THEN Test_1 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS Test1_Q1,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 91  AND 180  THEN Test_1 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS Test1_Q2,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 181 AND 270  THEN Test_1 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS Test1_Q3,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 271 AND 360  THEN Test_1 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS Test1_Q4,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF > 361 THEN Test_1 END),0)),2),'0') AS [> 1 YEAR],

    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN -365  AND -1 THEN Test_2 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS BEFORE_1_Yr,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 0   AND 90   THEN Test_2 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS T2_Q1,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 91  AND 180  THEN Test_2 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS T2_Q2,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 181 AND 270  THEN Test_2 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS T2_Q3,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF BETWEEN 271 AND 360  THEN Test_2 ELSE 0 END),0)),2),'0') AS T2_Q4,
    ISNULL(round(AVG(NULLIF((CASE WHEN dIFF > 361 THEN Test_2 END),0)),2),'0') AS [> 1 YEAR]
FROM (
    SELECT P.ID
          ,[Test_Date]
          ,Asmission_Date as First_Admission
          ,DATEDIFF(DAY,Asmission_Date,[Test_Date]) AS dIFF
          ,round(AVG(NULLIF(CAST(Test_1 as FLOAT),0)),2) as Test_1
          ,round(AVG(NULLIF(CAST(Test_2 as FLOAT),0)),2) as Test_2
          ,round(AVG(NULLIF(CAST(Test_3 as FLOAT),0)),2) as Test_3
          ,round(AVG(NULLIF(CAST(Test_4 as FLOAT),0)),2) as Test_4
          ,....
          ,......TEST_120
    FROM [AR].[Source].[VIEW_Test] P
    LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT ID,
                        MIN(Asmission_Date) AS Asmission_Date
                 FROM [AR].[Source].VIEW_Asmission 
                 GROUP BY ID 
               ) C
     ON P.ID=C.ID   
     GROUP BY P.ID,[Test_Date],Asmission_Date
  )  Q
```

Structure of the tables are as follows:

---

Admission Table

```
------------------------
ID     AdmissionDate     
------------------------
1      01/01/2010
1      01/10/2010 
1      01/01/2011
2      01/01/2012
2      20/06/2012       
3      30/03/2013       
------------------------
```

Test Table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ID     Test_Date       Test1   Test2  Test3...........Test120
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      01/01/2010        4.2     2      3
1      10/01/2010        2.0     4      4
1      01/05/2012        5.1     4      3
3      01/04/2013        1.2     6      1.9
3      05/04/2013        1.8     2      3
3      01/06/2013        2.1     3      3.2
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  First_Admission  Test1_Q1 Test1_Q2 Test1_Q3 Test1_Q4 T2_Q1 T2_Q2 T2_Q3 T2_Q4.......
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   01/01/2010          3.1      3      5.1        0
2   01/01/2012            0      0        0        0
3   30/03/2013          1.5    2.1        0        0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: SQL Server works better with 121 columns.

Comment: Do you need the data to be split out that wide? Think of how useless that is if displayed that way. I noticed you didn't type Test 1 thru test 120. I'm assuming the reason you didn't that is that it's a huge hassle.

Comment: Hi Zane, you absolutely right of the hassle and if i can control it with variables and loops would be great of my help... Also why I wants to split out that wide is because users are using SPSS(statastical tools) and for this they want all the data in one row per ID.